# Possible to do a callback in setState like this in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm now to react and I'm wondering if what I've done is a bad way of creating this component. What I wonder is: 
Is this the correct way to do the callback in the setState? If not, where should this line $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(data) be placed?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.id!== prevProps.id) {
        $.get('/webapi/GetData?id=' + this.props.id, function (data) {
            this.setState({ editorValue: data }, $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(data)); 
        }.bind(this));
     }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.initEditor();
    $.get('/webapi/GetData', function (data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
    }.bind(this));
}


 initEditor = () => {
        $("#editor").kendoEditor({ 
            value: this.state.editorValue,
        )}
    }
```

but this works?

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.get('/webapi/GetData', function (data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
        this.initEditor();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: The posted answer should do the trick.  Just wanted to point out that if you're using React you'll want to move away from using jQuery concurrently.  In addition to adding a larger dependency load, directly editing the DOM as jQuery does can interfere with React functioning as expected.  The data attributes you are dealing with can be passed to elements as props which are rendered in your component's render() function.

Answer (score 3):

To properly do a callback after setState follow this format:

```
this.setState( { foo: bar }, () => callbackFunction() )
```

> **EDIT**

To answer the second part of your question, you shouldn't need to use those lines of code at all. Let React handle the rendering. Say you have a render like so

```
render() {
    return(

        <div>
            <input type="text" name="someValue" data-kendoeditor={this.state.editorValue} />
        </div>

    )
}
```

Then call setState like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.id!== prevProps.id) {
        $.get('/webapi/GetData?id=' + this.props.id, function (data) {
            this.setState({ editorValue: data }); 
        }.bind(this));
     }
}
```

This will rerender the value from state to the DOM.

Comment: So what I have done in my code is unecessary? Should I place it under the setState instead?

Comment: It seems unecessary. Mainly because your callback seems to be using jQuery to update a data-attribute. The component will rerender when the state is updated so why not just replace the hardcoded data-attribute in the render with this.state.editorValue ? You should never have to use jQuery and react together, you should instead let react handle all the DOM changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's say I want to use this editor instead (which is the same as the kendo editor for jquery): https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-editor-react-wrapper

Is it possible for me to swap out my jquery with this one and just use state and same code in componentdidmount?

Comment: I've updated the topic with some more code. Could you take a look? :)